# Why are extra properties added to result set

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize-Mock and based on my model, I didn't expect there to be an `id property or timestamps` Is there a way to suppress those?

**mock.js**

```
var UserMock = DBConnectionMock.define('users', {
    'Property1': 5,
    'Property2': 10,
    'Property3': 15,
    'Property4': 25
})


// From there we can start using it like a normal model
exports.getTotals = () => {
    return UserMock.findAll().then(r => r);
}
```

**index.js** console.log results

```
[[ { Property1: 5,
    Property2: 10,
    Property3: 15,
    Property4: 25,
    id: 1,
    createdAt: '2018-07-28T03:54:14.442Z',
    updatedAt: '2018-07-28T03:54:14.442Z' } ]]
```

Comment: You can turn off timestamps (although you probably shouldn't). I doubt you can turn off IDs. http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html#configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable `timeStamps` set,

```
timestamps: false
```

To prevent creating primary key `id`, set any other column as primary key like,

```
Property1: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    primaryKey: true
}
```

Comment: How exactly do you set primary key in `sequelize-mock`? The 1st parameter is used for default values, the 2nd one for configuration.